# How to fix composer issue codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires dev.mikey179/vfstream, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your `composer.json`  and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name": "codeigniter/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "support": {
        "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
        "slack": "https://codeigniterchat.slack.com",
        "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.7",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "dev-master"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "dev.mikey179/vfstream": "1.1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
    }
}


need to remove and save it in composer.json

"require-dev": {
        "dev.mikey179/vfstream": "1.1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
    }

after removing this then all are good
```

Comment: While this will work, you have ignored the information the error message was giving you about where the problem was, and so won't be able to solve similar problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have a typo in the package name.

The default source for Composer packages is [Packagist](https://packagist.org/), which has a convenient package search.

Searching for "vfstream", we find that the top package is "mikey179/vfsstream", not "dev.mikey179/vfstream". The "dev." at the front of the name has been accidentally added in your `composer.json`.